# Change String length or decimal precision of field attribute dynamically

Tags: acumatica

I'm trying to use setup data from one table to allow me to format fields on the fly / dynamically.  I know I can change field names and visibility based on the PXUIFieldAttribute class, but changing the precision or string length is a bit trickier, obviously.  From the research I've done, I've come up with the following example code that seems like it should work - but I get the error:

"Unable to cast object of type 'PX.Data.PXUIFieldAttribute' to type 'PX.Data.PXDBDecimalAttribute'.

I don't see why this is occurring...

```
    protected virtual void xTACOpenSourceDetail_RowSelected(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        var osd = (PXCache)sender;

        foreach (PXDBDecimalAttribute attribute in this.Caches<xTACOpenSourceDetail>().GetAttributes("Number1"))
        {

            PXDBDecimalAttribute someAttribute = attribute as PXDBDecimalAttribute;
            if (someAttribute != null)
            {
                someAttribute.DBProperties._precision = 4;
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried the below code in sales order screen and it seems working!

```
        var props = typeof(SOOrder).GetProperties().Where(prop => Attribute.IsDefined(prop, typeof(PXDecimalAttribute)));
        foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo item in props)
        {
            PXDecimalAttribute.SetPrecision(this.Base.Caches[typeof(SOOrder)], item.Name, 1);
        }
```

You might need to change this to match your DAC.

Comment: Aside from needing to change PXDecimalAttribute to PXDBDecimalAttribute - that did the trick - thanks!

Comment: yea, sorry. i was just trying with that.